# One of the pod replicas fails liveness probe and restarts

Tags: elasticsearch, kubernetes, kubernetes-helm, kubernetes-pod, fluentd

Fluentd-elasticsearch pod is restarting too many times. Some of the pod don't have this problem. My guess is that Fluentd restarts because of some buffer problem.

When I look at the event log, it says

```sh
Container fluentd-elasticsearch failed liveness probe, will be restarted
```

Before the container restarts, it produces some logs, but I can't get what is wrong.

**Logs**: https://gist.github.com/eli-halych/a2ea69f708a83e07e907f79858941ba4#file-fluentd-elasticsearch-log

Another observation is that 2 replicas of the pod are running successfully. Only one replica has this problem and restarts many times.

**Fluentd setup YAML**: https://gist.github.com/eli-halych/a2ea69f708a83e07e907f79858941ba4#file-fluentd-setup-yaml

---

**Helm chart used**: https://github.com/kokuwaio/helm-charts/tree/main/charts/fluentd-elasticsearch

**Fluentd version**: 3.1.0

**Elasticsearch version**: 7.11.1

Comment: Here's the liveness probe: https://github.com/kokuwaio/helm-charts/blob/240daff48a80584020d657eaffdffc25db554f81/charts/fluentd-elasticsearch/values.yaml#L193-L226. You can configure its intervals from a custom `values.yml` file (or via command-line argments) and upgrade your deployment. You can also test by disabling it i.e. `enabled: false`.